# How to get median values across diagonal lines in a matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following matrix in pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10, 10)))
```

I need to get a vector that contains 10 median values, 1 value across each blue line as shown in the picture below:

[image]

The last number in the output vector is basically 1 number rather than a median.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
X = np.random.random((10, 10))
fX = np.fliplr(X) # to get the "other" diagonal
np.array([np.median(np.diag(fX, k=-k)) for k in range(X.shape[0])])
```

Comment: Hi agree with @Quang Hoang. I came to the same solution using `np.rot90` instead of `np.fliplr`

Answer (score 1):

The diagonals are such that `row_num + col_num = constant`. So you can use `stack` and sum the rows/cols and `groupby`:

```
(df_matrix.stack().reset_index(name='val')
   .assign(diag=lambda x: x.level_0+x.level_1)  # enumerate the diagonals
   .groupby('diag')['val'].median()             # median by diagonal
   .loc[len(df_matrix):]                        # lower triangle diagonals
)
```

Output (for `np.random.seed(42)`):

```
diag
9     0.473090
10    0.330898
11    0.531382
12    0.440152
13    0.548075
14    0.325330
15    0.580145
16    0.427541
17    0.248817
18    0.107891
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, in my real matrix I get this error a line `.assign(diag=lambda x: x.level_0+x.level_1) `: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'". Do you know why it may happen?

Comment: That's because your actual data has string column names. Try replaceing `df_matrx` with `pd.DataFrame(df_matrix.to_numpy())`.